# Regexp: using lookahead assertion as condition

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I believe the two regular expressions below do the same thing:

```
\ba{3}\b

(?=\ba{3}\b).*
```

Both would match the second word (aaa) only:

> zzz aaa bbb

I would like to know whether there's any difference between in terms of performance or any other aspect, or whether one is more advisable than the other for some reason.

**EDIT:**

It's true the patterns above match different things ("aaa" and "aaa bbb"). I'm sorry, my fault.

My original patterns were:

```
(?=^a{3}$).*
^a{3}$
```

and my original examples subject were:

```
zzz
aaa
bbb
```

Like that I think that both patterns match "aaa".

I understand that the second one is faster. Is there any other difference?

Comment: The second regex will match `aaa bbb`

Comment: The pattern are differents. But if they are the same the first is from far the fastest. An other thing, the first pattern match the first word not the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about Regular Expressions, three things come to mind:

1. The matching domain
2. Complexity
3. Speed

Simplicity of any Regular Expressions to match desired strings has a direct relationship with its speed so using less expressions you'll have better speed in searching through whole text.

Some expressions really cost a lot so when trying to select the best choice of your regex why should you think more?!

On the regex `^a{3}$` the engine will say: ***I really mean it!*** It's straight forward, simple with one obvious matching domain.

However in second one `(?=^a{3}$).*` engine doesn't mean it. It has probably so many matching cases, it has a positive lookahead and consume more resources.

Now, which one you're goin' to love?

Answer (score 1):

As Jerry points out in comment, the second one matches `aaa bbb`. However, personally I think it'd be simpler as `\ba{3}\b.*`

Comment: Oh hey, you changed your username and gravatar o.o